# OSGi java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/BundleContext

Tags: java, intellij-idea, osgi, jmf, jitsi

I'm new with OSGi and I'm having trouble trying to run an example of this library: https://github.com/jitsi/libjitsi

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/BundleContext
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
at org.jitsi.service.libjitsi.LibJitsi.start(LibJitsi.java:247)
at org.jitsi.service.libjitsi.LibJitsi.start(LibJitsi.java:180)
at com.dotsystem.AVTransmit2.main(AVTransmit2.java:327)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.framework.BundleContext
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

Do I need an external jar for osgi?

Answer (score 1):

A class not found exception on a core osgi class, seems that you are missing a jar/framework jar that implements OSGi specification. Check which OSGi implementation your target system supports. If you have choice in choosing you can try,

1. Apache felix OSGi
2. Eclipse equinox OSGi

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run example from IntelliJ it may be problem that you haven`t imported maven dependencies. When you import java project into IntelliJ you must also import its dependencies (they are not imported by default).

Comment: sorry for the dumb question but how do I import dependencies in IntelliJ ?

Comment: You may have to right click on the project -> Maven -> reimport