# Kafka Connect ClassNotFoundExceptions when running QuickStart example on windows

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I try to run the Kafka Connect example from the Quick Start Guide ([Step 7](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_kafkaconnect)) on windows. I run into a lot of `ClassNotFoundExceptions`:

```
c:\Progs\kafka_2.12-2.3.0>bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat "C:\Develop\deploy\kafka-connect-quickstart\connect-standalone.properties" "C:\Develop\deploy\kafka-connect-quickstart\connect-file-source.properties" "C:\Develop\deploy\kafka-connect-quickstart\connect-file-sink.properties"

[2019-08-28 14:15:43,532] WARN could not get type for name org.osgi.framework.BundleListener from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name org.osgi.framework.BundleListener
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:390)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:381)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:411)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:308)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:244)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:185)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:61)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:79)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.framework.BundleListener
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:388)
        ... 9 more
[2019-08-28 14:15:43,542] WARN could not get type for name org.apache.kafka.common.utils.MockTime from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
[2019-08-28 14:15:43,555] WARN could not get type for name com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
[2019-08-28 14:15:43,559] WARN could not get type for name org.scalatest.junit.JUnitSuite from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
[2019-08-28 14:15:43,577] WARN could not get type for name org.apache.kafka.clients.MockClient$MockMetadataUpdater from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
[2019-08-28 14:15:43,612] WARN could not get type for name org.easymock.IAnswer from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
[2019-08-28 14:15:43,620] WARN could not get type for name org.jboss.netty.channel.MessageEvent from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
[2019-08-28 14:15:43,652] WARN could not get type for name org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
[2019-08-28 14:15:43,663] WARN could not get type for name javax.mail.Authenticator from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
[2019-08-28 14:15:43,691] WARN could not get type for name org.apache.kafka.test.MockMetricsReporter from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
[2019-08-28 14:15:43,715] WARN could not get type for name javax.jms.MessageListener from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
[2019-08-28 14:15:43,733] WARN could not get type for name org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.ObjectMBean from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
[2019-08-28 14:15:43,744] WARN could not get type for name com.google.gson.JsonSerializer from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
[2019-08-28 14:15:43,771] WARN could not get type for name org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
[2019-08-28 14:15:43,777] WARN could not get type for name org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.MockAdminClient from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
[2019-08-28 14:15:43,817] WARN could not get type for name org.easymock.EasyMockSupport from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
[2019-08-28 14:15:43,826] WARN could not get type for name org.osgi.framework.SynchronousBundleListener from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
[2019-08-28 14:15:43,842] WARN could not get type for name jline.Completor from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
```

I tried it with version `2.11-2.0.0`, `kafka_2.12-2.2.0` and `kafka_2.12-2.3.0`. The exceptions are thrown in all of them.

I guess it is not a special behavior of the Quick Start Example but a general problem with the "connect classpath". Would love to solve this before investigation of other connectors.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43824079/5720818)

Comment: I think it is not a OSGi Problem. There is a lot more missing and it seems that the whole classpath is corrupt. Probably my fault, but I don't know why as I just unziped Kafka without any modifications.

Comment: Try using Java 8?